# Java, anyway to write to a file at a given index/position?

Tags: java

```
public void updateZip(String regionName, int chunkOffset, FileSystem zipfs, byte[] chunkData){
    Path dataFilePath = zipfs.getPath("/data.data");

    //create data file if does not exist
    try {
        Files.createFile(dataFilePath);
    } catch (IOException e2) {}

    OpenOption[] options = new OpenOption[] { StandardOpenOption.WRITE };

    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = Files.newOutputStream(dataFilePath, options);

        long fileSize = Files.size(dataFilePath);

        //build
        if(fileSize != this.regionSize){
            os.write(new byte[this.regionSize]);
            os.flush();
        }

        os.write(data, 0, dataLength);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way to write `data` to a given position within the file? Please note that I'm working with a FileSystem, so I can't use something like Random Access File.

Comment: Possibly taking the contents, storing it a variable, then appending the data to a certain index in the variable, then rewriting?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "to a given position"? A given line?

Comment: @X33 technically `OutputStream` class API doesn't have ability to do this. So probably you shouldn't use it. Tell us what task you are trying to do? May be it's possibly to do the task with different Java API.

Comment: You could try [`FileChannel.open()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-), but it depends on whether your `FileSystem` supports channels: *Throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if the path is associated with a provider that does not support creating file channels*

Comment: Is the file you are working with extremely large or will be in the future?

Comment: You can in-fact use RandomAccessFile. 
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(os, "name");
Refer: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/io/rafIO.html

Comment: @amitmah But that's not a valid constructor for RandomAccessFile? os is not a string, it's an OutputStream.

Comment: @RyanZink The file is around 50MB

Comment: Are you trying to write to the end of the zip entry?  Because [the documentation for Files.newOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) contains an example which does exactly that.

Comment: @VGR No, I'm just trying to write at a specific spot in the file. The entire file is full of bytes, and I'm trying to overwrite some bytes at a specific position.

Comment: @X33 did you read the reference: journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/io/rafIO.html 
As per this File object or String object can be passed in constructor.

Comment: @amitmah But you can't do that within a FileSystem. Trying to get `dataFilePath` as `File` object will just throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: Hi @X33 if you see my comment above (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(os, "name"); ) I passed OS object not dataFilePath.

Comment: Just check it out once and if it does not work try using java nio package

Comment: @amitmah What do you mean?? You can't construct a RandomAccessFile from an OutputStream object